# React - Video doesn't start on scroll if I change the source

Tags: video

I have this working component that contains a video that goes back and forth accordingly to the mouse Y scrolling.

When I change the source from a video I took online to a local one in my assets, the play on scrolling doesn't work anymore. Any hints?

```
import video from "/Users/username/Documents/my-app/src/assets/videos/video.mp4";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
  const scrollSectionRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [hasLoaded, setLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true);
    const playbackConst = 500; // Adjust the constant as needed
    // Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
    function scrollPlay() {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        const frameNumber = window.pageYOffset / playbackConst;
        videoRef.current.currentTime = frameNumber;
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;

    video?.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
      const { duration } = video;
      const playbackConst = 500;
      const scrollSection = scrollSectionRef.current;
      console.log("scrollSection", videoRef.current?.duration);
      if (videoRef?.current && scrollSection) {
        scrollSection.style.height =
          Math.floor(duration) * playbackConst + "px";
      }
      console.log(duration); // Output: video duration in seconds
    });

    return () => {
      video?.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {});
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          top: "0",
          left: "0",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          objectFit: "cover",
          zIndex: -1,
        }}
        ref={videoRef}
        id="v0"
        preload="preload"
      >
        <source
          type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'
          src="https://www.apple.com/media/us/mac-pro/2013/16C1b6b5-1d91-4fef-891e-ff2fc1c1bb58/videos/macpro_main_desktop.mp4"
        ></source>
      </video>
      <div ref={scrollSectionRef} id="scrollSection"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I just don't get the reason, if maybe the video needs to be preloaded somehow
Thanks a lot

Comment: Try replacing `type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'` with `type="video/mp4"` and see if that fixes it.